# Mapping non-normalized fields across tables

Tags: sql

I'm reading from a table that is not normalized (not my choice) and trying to map fields within it to another table. Is there a way to do this in one trip? I'm using Microsoft SQL.

```
TableA:
ID
FieldX1_ID (fixed set of fields that could have been better normalized)
FieldX2_ID
FieldX3_ID

TableB:
FieldX_ID (matches ID's in TableA's fields)
FieldX_Value
```

I would like the output rows to be:
TableA.ID, TableB.FieldX_Value for TableA.FieldX1_ID, TableB.FieldX_Value for TableA.FieldX2_ID, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results in two ways. I'm not sure from your description which one you're after.

To have the results appear in a normalized fashion (you get three rows):

```
 SELECT TableA.FieldX1_ID AS ID, TableB.FieldX_Value
   FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldX1_ID = TableB.FieldX_ID
 UNION ALL
 SELECT TableA.FieldX2_ID AS ID, TableB.FieldX_Value
   FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldX2_ID = TableB.FieldX_ID
 UNION ALL
 SELECT TableA.FieldX3_ID AS ID, TableB.FieldX_Value
   FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldX2_ID = Table3.FieldX_ID
```

To have the results appear in de-normalized fashion (you get one row):

```
 SELECT TableA.FieldX1_ID AS ID1, TableB.FieldX_Value AS Value1,
        TableA.FieldX2_ID AS ID2, TB2.FieldX_Value AS Value2,
        TableA.FieldX3_ID AS ID3, TB3.FieldX_Value AS Value3,
   FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldX1_ID = TableB.FieldX_ID
               JOIN TableB AS TB2 ON TableA.FieldX2_ID = TB2.FieldX_ID
               JOIN TableB AS TB3 ON TableA.FieldX3_ID = TB3.FieldX_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by joining tables A and B multiple times (once for each column in table A you need to join).

For example:

```
SELECT 
  A.ID
, FieldX1_Value = B1.FieldX_Value
, FieldX2_Value = B2.FieldX_Value
, FieldX3_Value = B3.FieldX_Value
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B B1
    ON A.FieldX1_ID = B1.FieldX_ID
LEFT JOIN B B2
    ON A.FieldX2_ID = B2.FieldX_ID
LEFT JOIN B B3
    ON A.FieldX3_ID = B3.FieldX_ID
```